# How to present a ViewController modally from the presentingViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers.

let's name them as A, B & C.

A presents B and then C should be present from A after dismissing B.

A <=> B

A -> C

How can I achieve this?
If the question is unclear then do let me know, I would be happy to edit it.

Comment: So A presents C after dismissing B? Make A a delegate of B and present C when B is being closed. Or use a Coordinator.

Comment: @Koen Yes, this is there. Definitely! But can I achieve something from inside B, directly?

Comment: Then you could use the `presentingViewController`, which should be A for B.

Comment: @Koen yes, that's what I did. Check out my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write a protocol in **B** like:

```
protocol VCBDelegate {
    func VCBDismissed()
}

Class VCB: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: VCBDelegate?
    ....
}
```

Now where you are dismissing B, call the delegate method in completion.

```
func dismissB() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegate.VCBDismissed()
    }
}
```

Now conform this protocol in **A**.

```
extension VCA: VCBDelegate {
    func VCBDismissed() {
        //Here you present C
        .....
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make the delegate self where you are presenting **B**.

Hope this helps, for any queries please feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside B try this

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {

    let aVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! AVC

    let cVC  = ///

    aVC.present(cVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This only works if aVC is the rootViewController. And I guess you meant cVC, not bVC?

Comment: @Koen according to the op a is the root , also inside callback he can present anything it's a typo

Comment: Where does the OP say that A is the root?

Comment: it's very clear from the question , you can also look to his posted answer to verify that

Answer (score 0):

Well, I achieved it this way.
Note: I am inside **B**.

```
let cViewController = // getting a handle of this view controller from Storyboard
let aViewController = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController

self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    aViewController?.present(cViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom notification observer like below:

In Controller A:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     // Register to custom notification 
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(presentC), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "BDismissed"), object: nil)

     // Rest of your code
}

func presentC {
 // Controller C presentation code goes here
}
```

In Controller B:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "BDismissed"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures, it's better and simple.
Your A will present B and give it a closure to call when it dismiss, this closure will present C.

Here is an example :

```
class ViewControllerA : UIViewController{

    func showViewControllerB(){
        let vc = ViewControllerB()
        vc.callOnDismiss = { [weak self] in
            self?.showViewControllerC()
        }
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

    func showViewControllerC(){
        let vc = ViewControllerC()
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}

class ViewControllerB : UIViewController{

    var callOnDismiss : () -> () = {}

    func actionOnDismiss(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.callOnDismiss()
    }

}

class ViewControllerC : UIViewController{

}
```